# How to open a table using sqlite db in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am using SQLite for Windows Phone 7 (http://sqlitewindowsphone.codeplex.com/) and I have done every steps from this tutorial (http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Native-Database-Programming-via-Sqlite-Client-for-Windows-Phone.aspx).

Then i try to create a simple application to select a entire table in a .sqlite database and show it into the windows phone textblock by pressing a button..

I done it, by the time of clicking the button, it shows "table does not exists". I want to know where to add our already created .sqlite db in our program? and how to open the db and show the table in windows phone. Please help me...  Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

After Mango Update About Windows phone it was have been support SQLCE. So in my Suggestion you can try fllow step by msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202860(v=vs.92).aspx

well . if you want to use SQlite .there may be have some problem . in isoloate Stroage you can't get database file.

in codeplex have opensource project : http://sqlitewindowsphone.codeplex.com/